# Why is VideoEncoder not available in my browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webcodecs, videoencoder

I'm using the latest version of Chrome. The specific error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: VideoEncoder is not defined".

Code that triggers error: let foo = VideoEncoder

Comment: @Robert alright, done.

Answer (score 1):

You must use https. On http sites VideoEncoder won't be defined.